Is the installation of Spamassasin (4.0.0-8ubuntu5) broken in Ubuntu Server 24.04? Or has something changed?
I am trying to install Spamassassin (4.0.0-8ubuntu5) on my VPS with Ubuntu Server 24.04.
With the command, sudo apt install spamassassin spamc, the installation is completed without an error message. However, when I run sudo systemctl enable spamassassin I get the following error message:
Failed to enable unit: Unit file spamassassin.service does not exist.

Unfortunately, I don't know what I can do to check what's going on.
In the log file, /var/log/mail.log, you can find the following:
2024-11-07T18:07:39.391194+01:00 crosis spamd[15368]: spamd: server killed by SIGTERM, shutting down
2024-11-07T18:07:40.558418+01:00 crosis spamd[17924]: zoom: able to use 388/388 'body_0' compiled rules (100%)
2024-11-07T18:07:40.974060+01:00 crosis spamd[17924]: spamd: server started on IO::Socket::IP [::1]:783, IO::Socket::IP [127.0.0.1]:783 (running version 4.0.0)
2024-11-07T18:07:40.974334+01:00 crosis spamd[17924]: spamd: server pid: 17924
2024-11-07T18:07:40.978836+01:00 crosis spamd[17924]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 17954
2024-11-07T18:07:40.982455+01:00 crosis spamd[17924]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 17955
2024-11-07T18:07:40.983479+01:00 crosis spamd[17924]: prefork: child states: IS
2024-11-07T18:07:40.983857+01:00 crosis spamd[17924]: prefork: child states: II

Has something changed? Does the service spamassassin.service no longer exist and now spamd is the replacement?

I don't have any answers but I can say I have the same problem. Have you had any luck resolving? New install of Spamassassin in Ubuntu 24.04 won't start
